# Matching ID_x with ID_x or cycling through id's with +i

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am looking to do something along these lines but have been getting stuck.

Basically I have a for loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var foo = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      $('#event_').attr('id', 'event_' + i);
      $('#unformatted_').attr('id', 'unformatted_' + i);
      $('#formatted_').attr('id', 'formatted_', +i);

    }

  };

  /* formatting date and time (from sql YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.0000 - need DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS  */

  /* this is where i want to do something like #unformatted + i to cycle through each span with #unformatted_ (1,2,3,4 etc), grab the html (the date and time), format them, and display them in #formatted_ (1,2,3,4 etc) but with the corresponding one of course*/

  var startdate = $('#unformatted_').html();
  var subyear = (startdate).substr(0, 4);
  var submonth = (startdate).substr(5, 2);
  var subday = (startdate).substr(8, 2);
  var starttime = (startdate).substr(11, 8);
  var subfull = (subday + "-" + submonth + "-" + subyear);
  $('#formatted_').html(subfull + " " + starttime);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="event_">
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="unformatted_">" . $row["date"]. " " . $row["time"]. "</span>
      <span id="formatted_"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="event_">
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="unformatted_">" . $row["date"]. " " . $row["time"]. "</span>
      <span id="formatted_"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="event_">
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="unformatted_">" . $row["date"]. " " . $row["time"]. "</span>
      <span id="formatted_"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Each #event_, #unformatted_, and #formatted_ gets a number put at the end. So all three ids in table 1 have the _1, in table 2 have _2.

I then need to take the text output in #unformatted_ (a date from an SQL table, echoed out with php, think calendar or agenda), once that's formatted by the variables grabbing the substr, it needs to be displayed in #formatted_. Currently I can only get the first table (#event_1) to display the #formatted_1 text, with #event_2 section of #formatted_2 empty (so on and so forth).

I've been as far as getting the #formatted_1 to display in #formatted_2 and #formatted_3, but I can't seem to get

```
#event_1 -> #unformatted_1 -> #formatted_1
#even_2 -> #unformatted_2 -> #formatted_2
..so on and so forth.
```

If you run the snippet you'll see what I'm talking about.

I'm fairly amateur so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Ps. In reading about ways to fix my issue I've seen a lot of talk about JSON & AJAX, should I be using these instead?

The site I'm building is basically an event website. So say it's for a comedy club. User goes to the site, views the custom built calendar (sql database for each show, echoing the rows through php), each month is it's own .php (ie. jan.php). I need to add addthisevent.com add this event button to each calendar entry, so users can easily add to google cal or ical. If you know of an easier way to do this I'm all ears! Or if theres a simple way to create an XML file readable by all google cal, ical, etc. which can be launched by user clicking on a link, I'm all ears for that as well.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm about as stuck as a bird with no wings in the middle of the ocean.

Comment: After the `for` loop, `$("#unformatted_")` won't find anything. It seems like you should be using classes instead of numbered IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all your spans the classes `class="unformatted"` and `class="formatted"` instead of ids. Loop through all of the `unformatted` elements getting each element's html (the date), reformat it, then use jQuery's `eq()` to set the modified text to the matching `formatted` element

```js
// give all your spans, classes `class="unformatted"` and `class="formatted"`
// loop through all of the `unformatted` elements

$('.unformatted').each(function(index, element){ 
      // use a regular expression to get an array of the different date parts
      // then rearrange them
      if($(element).html().match(/\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/)){
       var dateParts= $(element).html().match(/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/);
        // dateParts will now be an array with 4 items --> [YYYY, MM, DD, HH:MM:SS]
        // use jquery's `eq()` to set the modified text 
        // to the matching `formatted` element
        
       $('.formatted:eq('+index+')').html( dateParts[3]+'-'+
                                           dateParts[2]+'-'+
                                           dateParts[1]+' '+
                                           dateParts[4]    );
     }
});
```

```css
.formatted{
    
  margin-left:20px;
  color:green;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="unformatted">1983-12-22 06:22:25.0000</span>
      <span class="formatted"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table >
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="unformatted">1943-06-15 12:22:14.0000</span>
      <span class="formatted"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table >
  <th>Table Header</th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="unformatted">1999-12-04 02:22:27.0000</span>
      <span class="formatted"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```